# How render a list of options with renderOption in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the background colour of the options inside an `Autocomplete` component, and the closest I can get is by using the `renderOption` prop.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to iterate (using `map()`) the options that I have in my state.

What I would like to do is something like

```
{state.myOptions.map( option => {
    // here I would like to call renderOption = .....
}
```

Inside the `<Autocomplete/>` component

Is it possible to implement something like this or is there a well defined manner to do it?

EDIT

This is the component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm, Form } from './hooks/useForm'
import EventIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Event';
import { makeStyles, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import CustomTextField from './inputs/CustomTextField';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'




    const EventForm = (props) => {
    
        // Redux 
        const { family } = props
    
        // React 
        const initialState = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            errors: {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            },
            familyMembers: ["rgeg"]
        }
    
        const { state, handleOnChange, setState } = useForm(initialState)
    
        
    
        useEffect(() => {
            family && state.familyMembers !== family.members && setState({
                ...state,
                familyMembers: family.members
            })
        })
    
        // Material UI
        const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => (
            {
                message: {
                    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
                },
                icon: {
                    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
                    padding: "10px",
                    borderRadius: "50px",
                    border: "2px solid #3F51B5",
                    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
    
                },
                typography: {
                    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
                    marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
                },
                customTextField: {
                    marginTop: theme.spacing(0)
                },
                dateTimeWrapper: {
                    marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
                }
            }
        ))
    
        const classes = useStyles()
    
        return (
            <>
                <div>WORK IN PROGRESS...</div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <EventIcon className={classes.icon} />
                <Form
                    title="Add new event"
                >
                    <Typography
                        variant="subtitle1"
                        className={classes.typography}
                        align="left">
                        Enter a title for this event
                        </Typography>
                    <CustomTextField
                        className={classes.customTextField}
                        label="Title"
                    />
                    <Typography
                        variant="subtitle1"
                        className={classes.typography}
                        align="left">
                        Enter a location for this event
                        </Typography>
                    <CustomTextField
                        className={classes.customTextField}
    
                        label="Location"
                    />
                    <Typography
                        variant="subtitle1"
                        className={classes.typography}
                        align="left">
                        Which member/s of the family is/are attending
                        </Typography>
                    <Autocomplete
                        multiple
                        id="tags-outlined"
                        options={state.familyMembers}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                        // defaultValue={[familyMembers[0]]}
                        filterSelectedOptions
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label="Members Attending"
                                placeholder="Family Member"
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </Form>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    // Redux
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            family: state.auth.family
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventForm);
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole component's code?

Comment: sure, doing it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this took a while but the solution seems to use 'renderTags' algong with

here is the exact solution

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm, Form } from './hooks/useForm'
import EventIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Event';
import { makeStyles, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import CustomTextField from './inputs/CustomTextField';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import getColorvalue from './outputs/ColorValues'




const EventForm = (props) => {

    // Redux 
    const { family } = props

    // React 
    const initialState = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        errors: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        familyMembers: ["rgeg"]
    }

    const { state, handleOnChange, setState } = useForm(initialState)



    useEffect(() => {
        family && state.familyMembers !== family.members && setState({
            ...state,
            familyMembers: family.members
        })
    })

    // Material UI
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => (
        {
            message: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
            },
            icon: {
                backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
                padding: "10px",
                borderRadius: "50px",
                border: "2px solid #3F51B5",
                marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)

            },
            typography: {
                marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
                marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
            },
            customTextField: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(0)
            },
            dateTimeWrapper: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
            }
        }
    ))

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <>
            <div>WORK IN PROGRESS...</div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <EventIcon className={classes.icon} />
            <Form
                title="Add new event"
            >
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Enter a title for this event
                    </Typography>
                <CustomTextField
                    className={classes.customTextField}
                    label="Title"
                />
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Enter a location for this event
                    </Typography>
                <CustomTextField
                    className={classes.customTextField}

                    label="Location"
                />
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Which member/s of the family is/are attending
                    </Typography>
                <Autocomplete
                    multiple
                    id="tags-outlined"
                    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                        value.map((option, index) => (
                            <Chip
                                variant="outlined"
                                key={option}
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: `${getColorvalue(state.familyMembers[state.familyMembers.indexOf(option)].color)}`,
                                    color: "white"
                                }}
                                label={option.name}
                                onDelete={() => console.log("test")}
                                {...getTagProps({ index })}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                    options={state.familyMembers}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                    // defaultValue={[familyMembers[0]]}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Members Attending"
                            placeholder="Family Member"
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}

// Redux
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        family: state.auth.family
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to override the color of the option you can do it by overriding it's styles. No need to make custom option rendering function.

Above is the example of how can you achieve that.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm, Form } from './hooks/useForm'
import EventIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Event';
import { makeStyles, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import CustomTextField from './inputs/CustomTextField';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const EventForm = (props) => {
    // Redux 
    const { family } = props

    // React 
    const initialState = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        errors: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        familyMembers: ["rgeg"]
    }

    const { state, handleOnChange, setState } = useForm(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        family && state.familyMembers !== family.members && setState({
            ...state,
            familyMembers: family.members
        })
    })

    // Material UI
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => (
        {
            message: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
            },
            icon: {
                backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
                padding: "10px",
                borderRadius: "50px",
                border: "2px solid #3F51B5",
                marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)

            },
            typography: {
                marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
                marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
            },
            customTextField: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(0)
            },
            dateTimeWrapper: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(4)
            },
            option: {
              backgroundColor: 'red'
            }
        }
    ))

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <>
            <div>WORK IN PROGRESS...</div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <EventIcon className={classes.icon} />
            <Form
                title="Add new event"
            >
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Enter a title for this event
                    </Typography>
                <CustomTextField
                    className={classes.customTextField}
                    label="Title"
                />
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Enter a location for this event
                    </Typography>
                <CustomTextField
                    className={classes.customTextField}
                    label="Location"
                />
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.typography}
                    align="left">
                    Which member/s of the family is/are attending
                    </Typography>
                <Autocomplete
                    multiple
                    id="tags-outlined"
                    classes={{
                        option: classes.option
                    }}
                    options={state.familyMembers}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                    // defaultValue={[familyMembers[0]]}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Members Attending"
                            placeholder="Family Member"
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}

// Redux
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        family: state.auth.family
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventForm);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful, but what I am trying to change is the color of the small badge with the option selected. I have managed to do it with classes but I want to render every div based on the member color in the state, and the problem I have encountered is that I can't use backticks to dynamically target the "& MuiChip-root MuiAutocomplete-tag MuiChip-deletable[data-tag-index["whatever-the-index-is"]" property depending on the data-tag-index.

Comment: I have managed to target what I wanted, and namely 'tag', but still I can't figure out how to target it based on the data-tag-index dinamically