# Styling Material UI Autocomplete's option background color

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'd like to change the color behind the dropdown options in my Material UI Autocomplete component.

I've reviewed the below sources, but they only describe how to use the `renderOption` prop to render the option text itself, which results in something like the below picture:

- [Change the color of Material UI Autocomplete option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171767/change-the-color-of-material-ui-autocomplete-option)
- [How render a list of options with renderOption in material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225651/how-render-a-list-of-options-with-renderoption-in-material-ui)

[image: dropdown_option_with_only_text_colored]

**Instead, I want the entire option rectangle to be a certain color.** The entire rectangle encasing the dropdown options would be the color, not just the little bit surrounding the option text. I expect this to require some intelligent css styling, as it doesn't seem to be offered as a prop on the Autocomplete component, but I can't figure out the proper syntax/rules to change.

Bonus if you also explain how this could be done as global override. I've been unable to add an override, like [this](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/mui-org/material-ui/19692/590519218), even after extending the default theme. (See why extending the theme would be necessary [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19692#issuecomment-590520202).)

Comment: The answer in the first link should cover the entire background of option element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the classes property of Autocomplete.

Checkout the CSS section of https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Here is an incomplete example that will hopefully help you get started.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    option: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
}));

<Autocomplete
    classes={{
        option: classes.option
    }}
/>
```

I am not sure how you would do this as a global override.